# trouble deleting files from an external drive

Tags: macos, permission, external-disk

When I try to delete folders/files from my External drive I get the below error after being asked to enter my admin password:

`The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items.`

This volume is `Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)` and I am running `10.7.2`

Permissions seem correct `read/write` and everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Terminal
2. Drag folder you want to delete onto the Terminal icon in the dock
3. Type `cd ..` in the new Terminal window in order to move to the parent directory.
4. Type `ls` to find out the exact name of the files/folders in the directory.
5. Type `sudo rm -r filename` to delete the file/folder 'filename'. Be careful to type the correct name.

Dragging files onto the terminal icon does not work. You will need to drag the parent directory onto the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy, and this is (I think), a slight improvement on GentMatt's great answer...

Before his step 5, you can highlight and copy the filename in terminal.

Then sudo rm -r , then paste.

This assures you are in fact, deleting the correct file.. Sometimes, there are two files with very close names..

It's probably a good idea to copy/paste as much as possible, in order to a) be lazy, and b) be more accurate...

Hope this helps.